# I wanto to set a repeating command block with a command in it (always active) Minecraft 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used this command

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block {TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block {TileEntityData:{Command:"effect @a clear"}}"}}
```

It works fine, but the command block says "Needs Redstone", so I want to change that in "Always Active" how to do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure thathis one won't work the way you want it to, since you didn't escape the strings in the strings.

Comment: Like @Plagiatus said, you need to escape the strings inside the string: `/setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block {TileEntityData:{Command:"/setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block {TileEntityData:{Command:\"effect @a clear\"}}"}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `auto` NBT tag on the commandblock to 1. This will cause the "Always Active" option to automatically be selected.

Here's an example:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ repeating_command_block 0 replace {Command:"/say Hello",auto:1}
```